# Enforce that groupby on series maintains original column name

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For the specifics of a problem I am working on, it is necessary that every groupby operation does not lose column information. However I noticed that if you extract a single column during a groupby operation, it will drop the original column name from the aggregated column name (as in the code snippet below).

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['max','min'])
# Result
   max  min
A          
a    6    1
b    5    2
c    7    3
```

I would like to ensure that the term 'B' remains in the dataframe, whether as a multi-index or as a string.

Under circumstances (in particular where you are applying the aggregation to more than one column), I would expect a multi-index with 'B' a level above max and min. If I cast it as a groupby operation on a singleton list of columns then I can get this:

```
df.groupby('A')[['B']].agg(['max','min'])

    B    
  max min
A        
a   6   1
b   5   2
c   7   3
```

I would like the second one, but unfortunately due to the specifics of the work I am doing, I cannot enforce the type of 'B' being a singleton list. Is there any way for me to enforce keeping the original column name in the new aggregation in the pandas settings, or to override the series function that is causing this?

I would like the second one, but unfortunately due to the specifics of the work I am doing, I cannot enforce the type of 'B' being a singleton list. Is there any way for me to enforce keeping the original column name in the new aggregation in the pandas settings, or to override the series function that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   'B': np.random.randint(10, size=N)})

print (df)

   A  B
0  c  6
1  b  1
2  c  0
3  c  1
4  a  9
5  c  0
6  c  0
7  b  9
8  c  3
9  b  4
```

If need aggregate by all columns names without `A` use:

```
print (df.groupby('A').agg(['max','min']))
    B    
  max min
A        
a   9   9
b   9   1
c   6   0
```

If need custom names, use named aggregation:

```
print (df.groupby('A').agg(B_mycustom_max=('B','max'),
                           B_min=('B','min')))
   B_mycustom_max  B_min
A                       
a               9      9
b               9      1
c               6      0
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't actually have true control over the code that is going to be executed. I'm trying to automate dataqueries using a few GPT libraries, and those libraries will kind of write the code they want to. The reason why I was keen about overriding the methods or default behaviour is because then GPT can run pandas how it wants, but I can make sure that it doesn't accidentally get confused or drop information it will need in the future.

Comment: @LSR - `Is there any way for me to enforce keeping the original column name in the new aggregation in the pandas settings` I think not possible, `to override the series function that is causing this` - Not sure.